# stateful protocol implementation with scala/akka

Tags: sockets, scala, tcp, io, akka

i'm currently implementing a TCP server with scala/akka using a stateful, text-based protocol including handshakes and some back-and-forth of strings to exchange data.

Considering I'm getting a ByteString from the client, whats the recommened way of implementing the state that parses the string sent and decides which command should be send back?

i assume its something with http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html but i could not find a example so far with sockets.

thanks

Comment: Did you had a look at the new feature Akka I/O ? From what I've seen, it has been designed to deal with this kind of implementations.

You can find some information : 

- on the dedicated section in the Snapshot-documentation : http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/io.html

- a talk on this subject at scala Days : http://www.parleys.com/play/51c16569e4b0ed8770356815/chapter0/about 

- and an interesting blog post : http://hseeberger.github.io/blog/2013/06/17/introduction-to-akka-i-slash-o/

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take first at pipelines for proper string framing, coding/decoding and backressure: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/scala/io-codec.html

There is a simple example in the TCP section using pipelines: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/scala/io-tcp.html#Usage_Example__TcpPipelineHandler_and_SSL

(don't be confused that it uses SSL, you can leave that part out)

And yes, the FSM module is probably what you want to use to implement the protocol states.